# Find days remaining until due date minus weekends in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying to configure a formula using the function MAX and TODAY to return the days remaining until the due date minus the weekends.

I'm using the 'Timeline' column entry to calculate the 'Due' date column `=WORKDAY.INTL(Data!$H5-1,Data!$I5,1)`.
So, the issue I'm having and I'm not able to find why is within the 'Remaining(days)' column formula to find the remaining days from the current date today `=MAX(0,Data!$J5-TODAY())`.

[image: Excel, start date, timeline(days), due date, remaining(days)]

Any pointers or help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Here's a file I created recreating the issue I'm having.
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhFSazYw9XzujXjoqeZN5CIAS7RH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=IF([TimelineDays]<0,0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(TODAY(),[DueDate],1))`, this will return exactly the days remaining minus the weekends plus any days that are prior to your starting date if your start date is before today or the current date.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I wasn't understanding the arrangement of the formula that I needed to write. I hope this helps a lot of others.

Answer (score 1):

Excel's function NETWORKDAYS() does that.

> Returns the number of whole working days between start_date and
>   end_date. Working days exclude weekends and any dates identified in
>   holidays.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7

Comment: Oh, so no need to use TODAY() within the formula?

Comment: NetWorkDays() needs a Start date and an end date. The Start date can be expressed by Today(), of course, to get the number of days from now to an end date in the future.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't seen this comment before. This actually did work. I'll post my results.

Comment: So I'm getting halfway there. The formula =IF(DueDate<TODAY(),0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(TODAY(),DueDate,1)) works but then still adds days for anything it seems to be over 20 days left before the due date.

Comment: Not sure I understand. What adds days after Networkdays() is done? Can you please edit your question and give an example of the expected result? You seem to be expecting something different than just the number of work days between now and a future date. Is the number in Timeline somehow involved? If so, what is the logic in words?